# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.ServiceDescriptionWSDL.getWSDLLocation()

Tags: java, exception

I have created my Web Service Client from wsdl in NetBeans IDE 7.3 and when trying to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.ServiceDescriptionWSDL.getWSDLLocation()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getWSDLDocumentLocation(ServiceDelegate.java:623)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.isValidWSDLLocation(ServiceDelegate.java:742)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:59)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:36)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: could you share the code which is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The provided axis2 jar might be odler version like `'axis2-1.2.jar'`.

Provide latest jar file for `axis2-metadata-1.6.0.jar`

for refference check this all [jars](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.ServiceDescriptionWSDL)

Comment: I tried several versions of the same jar file axis2-metadata-1.6.0.jar, axis2-metadata-1.6.1.jar and axis2-metadata-1.6.2.jar but no use and the same error occurs again

Comment: **Any Suggestions will be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

this issue is always by jar version. make sure the older version not in the classpath, the jvm will load the jar in the classpath specified order. if the older version or other jar that has the class you want to load, then the class will be load.

i always try to solve it like this:

in eclipse, ctr+shift+t, input the class name "ServiceDescriptionWSDL", if you can see more than 2 results,  it means there are several jars in the classpath. you can choose each of them to check whether method getWSDLLocation() exists in the class by "package explorer" in eclipse. 
in my experience, you should find a ServiceDescriptionWSDL in some jar which does not contain the method getWSDLLocation(), then remove this jar out of your classpath, or move this jar behind the jar that has the method if you use the "-cp" to specify classpath.